# What's a cross-platform local music player with playlist sync capability?

Tags: sync, music

I own a Windows Desktop and a Macbook Pro laptop. I keep my all my files (including music files) synchronized between these two machines using [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).

I'm looking for a music player on which I could create playlists and have them somehow sync between these two machines. Spotify kind of solves this problem for me. My playlists sync. If I add a local music file in one of my playlists on one machine, the playlist entry automatically shows up on the other machine and Spotify is able to match it to a copy of the music file on that machine (as long the file is available there). The only problem here is if Spotify has also matched my music to it's online library, it starts playing ads (I only have the free version). Is there another music player app out there better suited to this scenario?